# creating service from executing a JAR file in UBUNTU

Tags: service, ubuntu-14.04, executable-jar, pid, java-service-wrapper

I'm trying to create a service from executing a jar file in Ubuntu machine. I have created a wrapper with the below [code](http://www.jcgonzalez.com/linux-java-service-wrapper-example)

```
#!/bin/sh
SERVICE_NAME=MyService
PATH_TO_JAR=/home/nani/Documents/My_Build_executable/My_Build-12-06.jar
PID_PATH_NAME=/tmp/MyService-pid
case $1 in
    start)
        echo "Starting $SERVICE_NAME ..."
        if [ ! -f $PID_PATH_NAME ]; then
            nohup java -jar $PATH_TO_JAR /tmp 2>> /dev/null >> /dev/null &
                        echo $! > $PID_PATH_NAME
            echo "$SERVICE_NAME started ..."
        else
            echo "$SERVICE_NAME is already running ..."
        fi
    ;;
    stop)
        if [ -f $PID_PATH_NAME ]; then
            PID=$(cat $PID_PATH_NAME);
            echo "$SERVICE_NAME stoping ..."
            kill $PID;
            echo "$SERVICE_NAME stopped ..."
            rm $PID_PATH_NAME
        else
            echo "$SERVICE_NAME is not running ..."
        fi
    ;;
    restart)
        if [ -f $PID_PATH_NAME ]; then
            PID=$(cat $PID_PATH_NAME);
            echo "$SERVICE_NAME stopping ...";
            kill $PID;
            echo "$SERVICE_NAME stopped ...";
            rm $PID_PATH_NAME
            echo "$SERVICE_NAME starting ..."
            nohup java -jar $PATH_TO_JAR /tmp 2>> /dev/null >> /dev/null &
                        echo $! > $PID_PATH_NAME
            echo "$SERVICE_NAME started ..."
        else
            echo "$SERVICE_NAME is not running ..."
        fi
    ;;
esac
```

but I'm ge stuck with the `PID_PATH_NAME`. what is this PID and what exactly I need to do to configure/create/modify this one? please help me.

Answer (score 1):

The term `PID` stands for Process IDentifier, and is a unique number each process gets. By saving the PID to a file, the system can later find the PID of the service, and will be able to, for example, send a stop-signal to the service when it should be stopped.

Comment: Thanks. but how to create one and where exactly I need to place that one? give me a detailed example

Comment: @Nani And whats wrong with the path and the script as it is now?

Comment: @ Joachim : I have created one wrapper with the mentioned code and have started the service but it is not running. when I tried to stop the service it says "/etc/init.d/Myserv: 31: kill: No such process". So I thought there might be something  I have missed with PID

Comment: @Nani That seems to indicate that the actual service program doesn't start. Do you get any error messages in the logs when the service is started? Does it depend on something else to be started first? And you should really model your service script on `/etc/init.d/skeleton`.

Comment: @ Joachim :  I don't see any error by running this service and of course no dependency is there for this execution

Comment: @Nani The process id you show (`31`) is very low, which means that your service could be started before networking is up and running, for example. I doubt Java is going to work properly without networking. Have the `/home` partition (if it's on its own partition) been mounted? Can the service reach all files and directories it needs? And if you try to start it when the system is up and running you most likely won't have any problems because everything is up and running. You should really check all logs (in `/var/log`) to see if everything is working okay.

Comment: @ Joachim : I found no such error in the logs. did I miss something while creating the service? I have created just the above stated wrapper and trying to start the service.